# Debug C++ program in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, debugging

I have written a simple C++ program like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello.";
    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to debug it. So what will be the command for it so my control goes to every line?

Comment: This tutorial says How to debug in 6 simple steps http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/debug-c-program-using-gdb/

Comment: You don't have to, your program has no bugs.

Comment: I know it's a joke, but I dislike how the focus of debuggers is on removing bugs. Debuggers allow us to understand programs in ways that would be impossible by just inspecting code.

Answer (score 35):

You can use [`gdb`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) for this:

```
$ gdb hello
```

This will start `gdb` and prompt you for what to do next. The `next` command executes one line of source and stops at the next line.

I found a basic [GDB tutorial](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/) that may be helpful.

Answer (score 18):

Don't forget to compile your source code using -g option.
Like this: `g++ -g helloWorld.cc`
This is going to create an a.out executable file.
You'll be able to debug your a.out exe using `gdb ./a.out` command.
Another tool you may use it's [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) basically a GUI for gdb.

Good luck

Answer (score 6):

I always thought ***emacs*** provided a pretty user-friendly front-end to gdb...

E.g.

- % g++ hello.cc -g -o hello
- emacs hello.cc
- [ *In Emacs* ] Escape-x gdb
- Emacs will say "Run gdb (like this): gdb ".
- Add your binary name ("hello").  (E.g. "Run gdb (like this): gdb hello".)
- Go to your hello.cc buffer.
- Use the emacs command 'gud-break' to set a breakpoint in gdb from your hello.cc buffer.  (Normally bound to "C-x space".)
- Go to your *gud-hello* buffer.
- Type "run" at the (gdb) prompt.
- Use [ **N** ] Next or [ **S** ] Step.  Or [ **C** ] Continue.  [ **BT** ] Backtrace is also useful.
- Note what happens to the little triangle in the leftmost column of your hello.cc buffer.

(That should suffice to get you started.  Emacs being emacs, there are always more features...)

Comment: I recommend compiling with `g++ -Wall -Wextra hello.cc -g -o hello` because compiler warnings are really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

If you want some user-friendly debugger, you can use Kdbg, which is basically a gdb frontend for KDE. Perhaps not so powerful as ddd, but easier to start with.

Answer (score 3):

In the C++ Programming course I did in Sweden there was a part of the laboratory about the GNU Debugger. I never used it after, but [here](http://www.cs.lth.se/EDA031/laborationer/laboratoryexercises.pdf) there is a paper explaining the basic usage, as far as I remember is in chapter 2.