# code::blocks debugger stops in wrong places (c++, windows 10)

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

in my code, I have a break point set at line 8. the debugger doesn't stop there, but DOES stop at line 40. (which is an if-statement in a function definition, if that matters).
-g is on, -s is not, it's built to debug, the file path contains no strange characters.

debugger log:

```
Starting debugger: C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args     C:/Users/John/Desktop/programming/roguelike/bin/Debug/roguelike.exe
done
Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Child process PID: 9152
At C:\Users\John\Desktop\programming\roguelike\roguelikesource.cpp:40
```

pressing continue while it's stopped at 40 gives

```
Continuing...
In RaiseException () (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll)
```

and pressing it again causes a generic error popup and gives

```
Continuing...
[Inferior 1 (process 9152) exited with code 0377]
Debugger finished with status 0
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another breakpoint on line 40, or even a bug there that is causing an exception? However, without seeing the code we cannot really answer this question.

Comment: @KenY-N if there is a breakpoint, it isn't visually represented and I don't know how else I would detect it. the code is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43240473/sdl-getrendererinfo-crash